# Linear Transformation of polynomials proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $T: P_n \rightarrow P_n$ by $T(p(x)) = p(x+1)$

1. Show that $T$ is a linear transformation.

   - Let $k \in \mathbb{R}$
   - $T(kp(x)) = kp(x+1) = kT(p(x))$
   - Let $p(x)$ and $q(x) \in P_n$
   - Then $T(p(x) + q(x)) = T(p(x)) + T(q(x)) = p(x+1) + q(x+1)$
2. Show that $T$ is one-to-one.
3. Show that $T$ maps $P_n$ onto $P_n$.

For 2 and 3 I am confused, I'm not sure how to prove them and also, how are they different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (3)

$$p(x)\in\ker T\iff Tp(x):=p(x+1)\equiv0\iff\;\forall\,r\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;p(r+1)=0$$

but as $\;r\;$ runs over all $\;\Bbb R\;$ *so does* $\;r+1\;$ , so taking $\;t:=r+1\;$ we get that

$$\;p(t)=p(r+1)=0\implies p(x)\equiv0\;\implies \ker T=\{0\}\;$$

For (4): a linear operator $\;T:V\to V\;,\;\;\dim V<\infty\;$ , it is true that $\;T\;$ is injective iff it is surjective iff it is bijective, and we've finished (you may want to apply the dimensions theorem here in case you
've doubts about this part. It's easy)